# What are the minimum permissions for connectionUsername when using ActiveDirectoryMembershipProvider

Tags: asp.net, security, active-directory

I am writing an ASP.NET application using ActiveDirectoryMembershipProvider, similar to the scenario outlined here:
http://channel9.msdn.com/wiki/securitywiki/aspnet2formsauthtoadrolesinadintranet/

As part of this setup, I configured ASP.NET Membership as follows:

```
     <membership defaultProvider="MyADMembershipProvider">
      <providers>
        <add
           name="MyADMembershipProvider"
           type="System.Web.Security.ActiveDirectoryMembershipProvider, System.Web, Version=2.0.0.0, 
                 Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a"
           connectionStringName="ADConnectionString"
           connectionUsername="testdomain\administrator" 
           connectionPassword="password"/>
        </providers>
      </membership>
```

This works, but in production I would like to use a connectionUsername with minimum permissions to anything else, instead of "Administrator".  What are the minimum permissions that should be assigned to this account?

Comment: Do you need to perform any updates back to AD or do you want read-only access?

Comment: I'm pretty sure it's read-only, unless ADMembershipProvider is doing something weird in ValidateUser like updating the record.  We're not using Registration or anything like that.

Comment: Any read only user in AD should be fine then, I've done some stuff that updated phone numbers and department numbers back to AD, for that you would need privilideged user.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

See the note in the "Connecting to Active Directory" section at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms998360.aspx.