# Active Directory Membership Provider works only for the Administrator

Tags: asp.net, active-directory, asp.net-membership, membership-provider

Good day, I am pulling my hair on this one..
I have Active Directory Memebership Provider configured like this:

```
<system.web>
<membership>
<providers>
<clear/>
<add name="dev"
 type="System.Web.Security.ActiveDirectoryMembershipProvider, System.Web,       Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a"
 connectionStringName="DevTestConnStr"
 attributeMapUsername="sAMAccountName"
 connectionUsername="dev\Administrator"
 connectionPassword="Password" 
 applicationName="/web"  
  />
```

The provider is instantiated correctly but when I call this:

```
var user = Membership.Providers["myDomain"].GetUser("myUser", false);
```

the call always returns null, except the case when I pass **"Administrator"** into the call... I have run out of ideas on how to make it work. Please help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just as when I was already ready to bail, I decided to change my LDAP connection string from:

```
"LDAP://dev.local/CN=Users,DC=Dev,DC=local"
```

to

```
"LDAP://dev.local/DC=Dev,DC=local".
```

Now works as expected!

Answer (score 2):

You may want to check [this MSDN article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms998360.aspx).

From the article...

> The service account that you use to
>   connect to Active Directory must have
>   sufficient permissions in Active
>   Directory. If you place your user
>   accounts in an Active Directory
>   organizational unit (OU), you can
>   create and use a service account that
>   has only read, write, and delete
>   access on that OU (and, optionally,
>   reset password privilege).

Also, [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/674703/what-are-the-minimum-permissions-for-connectionusername-when-using-activedirector).